# how to get a date a week from now on in python?

Tags: python, datetime

how do I get todays date and the date a week from now on in ddmmyy format? I'm trying this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
date2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
```

if I comment date2 line, it return the date1 just fine, but for date2:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I just want the date, not time. Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You import datetime from datetime, so you need to remove one datetime from date2:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
```